# Locking Windows Phone with Custom Screen C#

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, locking

I need to lock Windows Mobile Screen (**without using default locking system**) on perticular activity.

I have seen on web that developers are using **SHDeviceLockAndPrompt** or **EnableHardwareKeyboard** for achieving lock.

This will show default window lock screen. I need to show **my screen with own checking of password with my own database**. How can I show my screen and lock device screen (hardware keys and keyboard, incoming phone calls, notifications etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all deponds on how secure you wont it to be. You will get the best security if you use windows mobile's own lock screen and then customize it ( Windows Mobile 6.5 I think it can be done quit nice ).

If it not a top notch security thing you can always make your own application be the top most, add the stuff you like on that view. Then use: SetWindowsHookEx ( Sorry I can't hyperlink, to bad reputation ... just search on MSDN ) to hook up on all the hardware buttons and return non zero to prevent other parts of the system to handle them. Have a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/raffael/setwindowshookex-on-windows-mobile)

To really prevent the user from accessing anything behind the view you can remove the start menu by puting it outside of the view. Use SetWindowPos Function

Comment: The start menu thing is only if you need to do stuff in the background, than it can pop down. I have found this trick good to prevent it.